# How to download Miles Reid's Algebraic Geometry video on Windows and view it offline

Tags: windows-7, video, download

I would really like to augment my knowledge of Algebraic Geometry from the lectures by Miles Reid which can be found [here](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/staff/Miles.Reid/AGvid.html). However, since I do not have fast Internet all the time, I am searching ways to download these lectures and view them offline.

This question was asked [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78037/video-lectures-for-algebraic-geometry/90670#90670) but the answer is for Linux platform and I think this is the appropriate forum to ask for help.

Can you please help me download? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Download Helper addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/video-downloadhelper/) for firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Use a download manager such as [Free Download Manager](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/) and add all the files to it. Download overnight or schedule to download when your Internet bandwidth allows. You can pause and resume the downloading even.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a mplayer port for windows, but VLC will save streams as well

- Select File->Open Network Stream
- paste the link in
- select "convert" from the drop down menu and select a file to save it as

Comment: thank you for your answer. When I click on the video it downloads an .asx file and which I can open in RealPlayer to view it live. But I do not know how to get the url since the video does not stream in my browser but in a media player instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you wget the file and open it in a text browser then you will find the URL inside.

E.g. I just downloaded the first lesson via these steps:

1) open in new tab in browser. This also opened a media player in my case

2) Notice the URL. ( http://www.mathnet.or.kr/real/2009/7/MilesReid%280709%29.asx )

3) wget http://www.mathnet.or.kr/real/2009/7/MilesReid%280709%29.asx

4) vim MilesReid(0709).asx

Inside was mms://kentro.kaist.ac.kr/200907/MilesReid(0709).wmv